# Subtract x amount of days from the start date (Python)

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have tried everything but I can't get it to work. I want to subtract x amount of days from the start date.

```
import datetime
import timedelta

start_date = datetime.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

end_date = (start_date - timedelta(days=3)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

When running the code I get this error:

[image: Error]

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please dont post images, paste the text of the error into the question so we can see it.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a great guide on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime.timedelta()` instead and not `strftime` on first date, because it turns it into `str`, when work is done you can do it later:

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime.today()

end_date = (start_date - datetime.timedelta(days=3)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

start_date = start_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

print(start_date)

print(end_date)
```